# Data request: NBA data to practice statistical programming

Tags: data-request

*I originally posted this in StackOverflow but it was recommended that I post here instead. Any feedback would be helpful!

My question: Any recommendations on where I can find boxscores for every game in the 2013-204 NBA season?

I'm learning R, and want to put my fledgling skills to the test with some analysis to use for my fantasy basketball team.

I'm trying to find box scores for every game in the 2013-2014 NBA season so that I can calculate standard deviation among top scorers/blockers etc.

After looking for a few hours I haven't been able to find this box-score archive for last year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reputation too low to comment (could someone please change this into one?).

For older data: http://www.databasesports.com/

Comment: It is good as an answer. Could you please detail the URL where NBA data can be found though?

Comment: http://www.databasebasketball.com/ (linked from the front page of above)

Comment: I guess http://www.databasebasketball.com/leagues/leaguelist.htm is the page that contains everything?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I think so (from that page, or pages linked from that page), but, to be honest, I haven't really used the site, and am just aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

This person's blog claims to have done what you are looking for and has a download version of game/box score stats since 1985/6 season.

http://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/crunching-30-years-of-nba-data-with-mongodb-aggregation/

Another alternative is to get the data from the NBA's statistics page. But there is no direct download. It's all interactive and tedious.

http://stats.nba.com

This site will sell you the data. Two seasons is about $50

http://downloads.nbastuffer.com/nba-team-data-sets