# NBA game timeseries data

Tags: data-request, sports

ESPN provides [NBA "game flow"](http://www.gilliganondata.com/index.php/2009/03/28/data-visualization-march-madness-style/) data, which show the score for each team over the course of the game. It's just a timeseries - score per team per timestep (assuming minute) of the game.

Other [posts](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/data-request-nba-data-to-practice-statistical-programming) have asked for game scores, which appear to be available [here](http://www.databasebasketball.com/leagues/leagueyear.htm?lg=N&yr=2010). I want the timeseries of score per team per timstep for each team, which isn't addressed by the prior post.

Where I can find (or scrape) this kind of data for historical NBA games (e.g., this season)?

Comment: Perhaps you can scrape the final charts from the webpage for each game (I don't know how long ESPN makes them available) and then write code to extract the time series from the graphs. It wouldn't be easy but should be doable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data request: NBA data to practice statistical programming](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/data-request-nba-data-to-practice-statistical-programming)

Comment: @philshem yes, saw that. i'm specifically interested in the game timeseries data over the course of each game whereas that request seems to simply ask for game final scores.

Comment: Good day ! Past season data NBA games you can try to find at the [1]: http://goalserve.com
They XML feed include live player stats , fixtures and past season data.

Answer (score 1):

[Sports Data Feeds](http://goalserve.com)
Good day ! Past season data NBA games you can try to find at the Goalserve. They XML feed include live player stats , fixtures and past season data.

Comment: whoa, thats an old espn theme. this is interesting, to say the least